# Artix signature is unknown trust

Tags: linux, signature, archlinux, pacman-package-manager, keyring

I installed artix-mate-openrc a day ago. Their  repo is too short and I wanted to add archlinux repo (community and extra) to add alacritty and other apps I needed. They do have a program in their repo (artix-archlinux-support) which adds it for you but I have a problem with that. You can see it in the output. I tried to fix it according to artix wiki but it failed.

OUTPUT FROM: `sudo pacman -S artix-archlinux-support`

```
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (3) archlinux-keyring-20220727-1  archlinux-mirrorlist-20200920-1
             artix-archlinux-support-2-1

Total Download Size:   0.02 MiB
Total Installed Size:  1.58 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
:: Retrieving packages...
 archlinux-mirrorlist-202009...     6.4 KiB  5.14 KiB/s 00:01 [---------------------------------] 100%
 artix-archlinux-support-2-1-any   14.6 KiB  9.55 KiB/s 00:02 [---------------------------------] 100%
 Total (2/2)                       21.0 KiB  11.6 KiB/s 00:02 [---------------------------------] 100%
(3/3) checking keys in keyring                                [---------------------------------] 100%
(3/3) checking package integrity                              [---------------------------------] 100%
error: archlinux-keyring: signature from "Dudemanguy <dudemanguy@artixlinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/archlinux-keyring-20220727-1-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] Y
error: archlinux-mirrorlist: signature from "Dudemanguy <dudemanguy@artixlinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/archlinux-mirrorlist-20200920-1-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] Y
error: artix-archlinux-support: signature from "Dudemanguy <dudemanguy@artixlinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/artix-archlinux-support-2-1-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] Y
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Answer (score 2):

The keyrings are corrupt and you delete them.

Try to install them with:

```bash
sudo pacman -Sy artix-keyring 
sudo pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring 
sudo pacman -Syu artix-archlinux-support
```